# Vector subscript out of range (but not really)

Tags: c++, runtime-error, stdvector, subscript

I'm using a function to fill a vector with random template (testing using doubles) values:

```
    template <typename T>
    void setList(vector<T> & theList)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));          

        int howMany, max, min;
        cout << "How many items should be generated in the list? ";
        cin >> howMany;
        cin.ignore();

        cout << "Max value of list? ";
        cin >> max;
        cin.ignore();

        cout << "Min value of list? ";
        cin >> min;
        cin.ignore();

        theList.resize(howMany);

        T randValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; ++i)
        {
            randValue = (((double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX) * (max - min)) + min;
            theList[i] = randValue;
        }
    }
```

The function is called in main on a vector:

```
    vector<double> listA;
    setList(listA);
```

No matter what value "howMany" is, when I reach subscript howMany-2, I am getting a subscript out of range error.

Stepping through the debugger, my index is within the subscript range.

For example, if user enters 10 for howMany, when the loop tries to enter

```
theList[8] = randValue;
```

The error is thrown.

Any ideas?

Comment: can it be because `list` is also an STD class? and why you use Template method as your vector holds integer by definition, isn't it?

Comment: @NirMH, that was my first intuition, but that changed nothing - list is correctly being identified as a variable name, not as a list object.  I've rewritten the code to verify and still getting the same error.

Comment: what error? can you log the size of `list` and `i` in the loop?

Comment: Show us how you call this function, and how do you generate the vector that you pass into it.

Comment: Error is Debug Assertion Failed! vector subscript out of range

Comment: can you show us the value of `howMany` during the `theList.resize(howMany)` statement?

Comment: maybe adding `list.reserve(howMany)` will solve the problem.

Comment: @40two, yea, I thought about that as well. That's weird, however, since `vector::resize` should create new elements properly if the new size is bigger than the previous size. It's worth a try for the OP though.

Comment: theList.resize(howMany) is working correctly - the debug is showing the vector being resized to howMany after that line and during the loop is the correct size.

Comment: @40two, I tried reserve(), which I believe just sets the capacity without setting the size of the vector, to no avail.

Comment: Hm.. actually, I just compiled that, and it worked fine (ubuntu 14.04/GCC 4.8)

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall, Perhaps Visual Studio is just being a jerk?

Comment: Maybe try to use `at` instead of `[]` and compile in release mode to check?

Comment: Well, I certainly fail to see any mistake here... Try to recompile it from scratch, as weird as it sounds, sometimes that helps in case the previous compilation went wrong for a reason.

Comment: @user1781290, No luck.

Comment: Does it throw the `std::out_of_range` properly when you use `at()`?

Comment: @40two How could calling `reserve` fix anything?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall, pardon my ignorance, how would I compile from scratch?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall, The same "Debug Assertion Failed! with Expression: "vector subscript out of range" error popping up.

Comment: Delete everything that was left from the previous compilations (visual studio should actually have an option to `clean`, but you can as well do it manualy), and recompile. Also, try to catch the exception: `try { theList.at(i) = randValue; } catch (const std::out_of_range& err) {
    std::cerr << "Out of Range error: " << err.what() << '\n';
}`, and look if that line gets printed out.

Comment: @juanchopanza I thought that maybe by setting the vector's reserved memory to be at least as `howMany` and then resize the vector to have the same number of elements, out of range error would have been avoided.

Comment: @40two OK, but there is no way that would work (unless that implementation of `std::vector` was broken.)

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall cleaning the solution did the trick!  Glad my code wasn't the culprit, blame MS.

Comment: @40two: That should really not be necessary. `reserve` is more of a storage hint to optimize performance. It's useful if you for example want to add a bunch of elements with `push_back`, and already know how many elements you will add. In this case, calling `reserve` ahead of time will avoid reallocations later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this code in a Solaris envioronment and I have not got the out of range index exception.

This is my code:

```
 template <typename T>
 void setList(std::vector<T> & list)
 {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int howMany, max, min;
    std::cout << "How many items should be generated in the list? ";
    std::cin >> howMany;
    std::cin.ignore();

    std::cout << "Max value of list? ";
    std::cin >> max;
    std::cin.ignore();

    std::cout << "Min value of list? ";
    std::cin >> min;
    std::cin.ignore();

    list.resize(howMany);

    T randValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; ++i)
    {
       randValue = (((T) rand() / (T) RAND_MAX) * (max - min)) + min;
     list[i] = randValue;
    }
    // I Have added this feature for visualization purposes
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
    {
       std::cout << "list[" << i << "]=" << list[i] << std::endl;
    }
  }
```

And my main() looks like

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     std::vector<int> lista;
     lista.clear();
     setList(lista);
 }
```

My output is:

[image: My execution output]

By the way I have noticed that if you define a vector of integers, the content of the vector is always the min value. This is because you need to cast the intermediate values to double and cast finally the result to type T. (In the intege type the "/" operator is interpreted as an integer division).

You could do this.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < howMany; ++i)
 {
     randValue = static_cast<T>((static_cast<double>((T) rand()) / static_cast<double>((T) RAND_MAX)) * (max - min)) + min;
     list[i] = randValue;
 }
```

Comment: I didn't catch the bug with integers, yet - thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my dilemma was provided by @SingerOfTheFall.

Specifically, getting a nonsensical error when debugging (in this case, an out of range while actually within the range) calls for testing different avenues.

If loading in a different compiler shows the code runs fine, the issue is then not necessarily with the code.

Recompiling the code from scratch ("cleaning") the code did the trick in this situation.